# HttpFoundation Session stand alone component and forms renderer

Tags: php, symfony

(I deleted previous similar subject, because there was too many changed in the code).

I use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` and `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` but without all framework.

I have simple index

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$session = new Session();
if(!$session->isStarted()){
    $session->start();    
}
$request->setSession($session);
$kernel = new Kernel(new AppContainer());
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

it works well when I use just twig templates.
When I use any class what implements `FormRendererInterface` it throw me an error.
I expect that by `CsrfTokenManager`.

[image]

This problem doesn't exists when I use `$session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());` in index.php. Unfortunately in such case sessions in the next request are empty (this is logic, because I sessions  auto start in php.inii is disabled).

Bellow is code what I use in the controller to use form builder.

```
...    
$form = (new LoginForm($this->formBuilder))->getForm($this->generateUrl('login'));
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            Match::val($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
            ->of(
                When::equals(true, function($item) use ($form){
                    $this->commandBus->dispatch(new UserLogin($form->getData()));
                }),
                When::other(false)            
            );
...
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: @gp_sflover done, will accept it in 2 days. Now I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

The issues was because to build form I use class `FormBuilder` what is abstract for others forms and it was provided as service.
There is creating csrf token and to do it I need to session instance.

I could not fond sessions in this class because it was configured in AppContainer.
So finally I had session what was start in the index.php and next try to start in the `SessionTokenStorage`. It has been throwed an error.

Now session is create in the AppContainer as public service.
I can set the same instance as parameter for others services and also add to the request by $appContainer->get('sessions').

Little bit of code

services.yaml

```
  ...
  sessions: 
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
    arguments: []
    public: true
  form.builder:
    class: Iaso\Web\Component\Form\FormBuilder
    arguments: ['@twig','@config.loader', '@sessions']
    public: true
```

index.php

```
<?php
...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$appContainer = new AppContainer();

$session = $appContainer->get('sessions');

if(!$session->isStarted()){
    $session->start();    
}
$request->setSession($session);

$kernel = new Kernel($appContainer);
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```